# Convert Postgres interval to PHP DateInterval

Tags: php, postgresql, date, dateinterval

I am saving a value into a Postgres10 `interval` type field.

When I return the field, I get the following: `3 years 10 mons 1 day 02:18:00`

The problem I seem to be having, mostly, is that it would also return `1 day 02:18:00` if the duration is not years and months long.

Is there a clean way to convert this value into a PHP DateInterval object?

I figure I can use regex but that seems a little messy to me.

Comment: `mons`? Is that correct? Do you mean the code should account for non standard words?

Comment: This is a direct copy of the database field value, yes.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the interval output style to `iso_8601` using

```
SET intervalstyle = 'iso_8601';
```

You will get output in the correct format for a call to `DateInterval::__construct` e.g.

```
SELECT
 INTERVAL '6 years 5 months 4 days 3 hours 2 minutes 1 second';
```

Output:

```
interval
P6Y5M4DT3H2M1S
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=5965ddf547901432d5f429da3e2e5ce6)

Comment: I am using Symfony with Doctrine. Any advise on how to handle through this?

Comment: @Wildcard27 I don't really know Symfony/Doctrine. But can't you just run a query to set the variable and then run your query on the table with the interval in it?

Comment: You can probably use [Pomm Interval converter](https://github.com/pomm-project/Foundation/blob/master/sources/lib/Converter/PgInterval.php).